# Obtain numbers from a field and process them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field which obtains it input through a list of links associated with numbers. (Similar to a calculator but without operators). I want to retrieve these numbers and put them through a function which divides them by 12. (A conversion from feet to inches).

First I have a list of jQuery click functions like this:

```
$('#a0').click(function(){
    writeInput(input, one); // var one = 1;
});
```

Next I have the function "write Input" (This is where the numbers are displayed on a "screen")

[image]

```
function writeInput(field, str){
    $input = $(field);
    var text = $input.val($input.val() + str);
    $input.text(text);
    convert(text);
}
```

And lastly I have a function which is supposed to divide the number inputted by 12

```
function convert(input){
    var divide = (input / 12);
    $("#output").html(divide); //output is a paragraph where the number is displayed
}
```

When I run my code I am getting **NAN** output where the number should be. I have tried parseInt() and other tricks. But the closest I have come to something correct is when I got [object] [object] output.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `text` is a jQuery object, you are using `val` as setter which returns a jQuery object, you should use `val`/`text` method as a getter for retrieving updated value.

```
function writeInput(field, str){
    var text = $(field).val(function(i, v){
                  return v + str;
               }).text(function(i, t){
                  return t + str
               }).val();
    convert(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly! Every time I ask a question on Stack Overflow I always learn something new :)